# Recover emails from Qmail

Tags: email, qmail

I installed Kloxo on a dedicated server (CentOS 5) a long time ago.  Now I'm moving everything to another dedicated server with another control panel.

I moved all the websites and databases, but not the emails as I didn't need them.  Now I need them (just some), and I would like to know if it's possible to get them even in raw plain text from a database or anything in the old dedicated server. (I can't access the webmail anymore cause I messed up kloxo installation, and the original server just messes up... I don't want to reintall it until I recover the emails.)

So the question is, does Qmail store its email in a database? If so, where is that database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Qmail is deployed to store e-mail messages in the [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) format, where each message is stored as an unique file. They can easily be copied.

The actual location of those files depends on your setup.

`$HOME/Maildir/` is quite a common location.

It is common to combine Qmail with [vpopmail](http://www.qmailwiki.org/Vpopmail) and you could try `vuserinfo -d emailaddress` to find a Maildirectory.

Comment: I just found that Maildir folder, I tried to read one mail (a plain text file) but after the header of the mail is the body, but its seems somehow encrypted, the first words in everyone of them is:

----boundary_

Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: The vpopmail binaries might not be installed in your default `$PATH` and you'll need to use the absolute path. `rpm -ql vpopmail`  (maybe followed by `| grep vuserinfo`  ) should show you where.

Comment: Each email message is a complete email. If I recall correctly each message is a RFC822 compliant (MIME formatted)  and if you copy them to a PC and add the filename extension `.eml`  they should open in your default mail client.

Comment: I've moved them into a working maildir folder in the new dedicated servers, and I can read all of them from the webmail (roundcube)... Thanks you so much, I've been trying to recover them since the last week...